# Earn from direct link

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Is there any way to earn from direct links? For example, someone will search for a specific file, as soon as he finds it, he will click in download link (which will be direct link), when he clicks in direct link, he will be redirected in a page with advertisements and a download button.
Is it possible to be automatically applied to every file in specific folder or subfolder inside mysite.com/directory/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the correct format to be asking this question, but you should look into Affiliate Tracking if the website you are trying to drive content to supports it.

Comment: no, ill allow users to upload in a website, this website will have mirrors, and will provide direct links to its users, and if someone from other website clicks my mirror (direct link) i will earn.

Comment: This not possible, and quite frankly sounds dubious legally and ethically.